# how to get current url from codeception & phantomjs test?

Tags: php, phantomjs, codeception

I am creating product in estore with my test, and need to get url after submitting a form.

Is it possible to get url *in the test scope* after submitting button ?

```
$I->click('#formSubmit');
$I->wait(5); // wait for redirect to new url
$url = $I->someFunctionToGetCurrentUrl()`
```

I am running this test from console, not from the web browser, so I don't have access to $_SERVER that is on the server's side.

But if I have some methods like `$I->canSeeCurrentUrlEquals()` in codeception framework then i should somehow be able to access current url...

how to do it?

Comment: what do you mean by "in the test scope"?

Comment: I am running this test from console, not from the web browser, so i dont have access to $_SERVER that is on the server's side. But if I have some methods like `$I->canSeeCurrentUrlEquals()`  in codeception framework then i should somehow be able to access current url... how to do it? that is the question...

Comment: Please edit your question to include this additional information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution was to add a helper method to AcceptanceHelper in _support/AcceptanceHelper.php file:

```
    class AcceptanceHelper extends \Codeception\Module
    {

        /**
         * Get current url from WebDriver
         * @return mixed
         * @throws \Codeception\Exception\ModuleException
         */
        public function getCurrentUrl()
        {
            return $this->getModule('WebDriver')->_getCurrentUri();
        }

    }
```

and then use it in test:

```
$url = $I->getCurrentUrl();
```

Comment: I only get the path part of the URI/URL, never the full thing (including http).

Comment: I hope it is useful to someone, to get complete URL with protocol etc. replace return statement with this: 
return $this->getModule('WebDriver')->_getUrl().$this->getModule('WebDriver')->_getCurrentUri();

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have an AcceptanceHelper/FunctionalHelper class (and so $this->getModule or $this->client are undefined) then the following in your  AcceptanceTester/FunctionalTester class should work:

```
public function getCurrentUrl() {
    return $this->executeJS("return location.href");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CodeCeption's PhpBrowser function `grabFromCurrentUrl()` to get the current URL.

https://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#grabFromCurrentUrl

This function accepts regex to return a specific portion of the current URL, however also...

> If no parameters are provided, the full URI is returned.

So, use it like this

```
$uri = $I->grabFromCurrentUrl();
```